# Obtaining the absolute difference between consecutive elements in an array, and returning which difference occurred the most

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

So if there's an array like [2, 3, 5, 7, 11], the differences would be 1, 2, 2, 4, therefore you'd return 2.

Brute force would be to just iterate over the initial structure, store each calculated difference in a new structure, and count the most number of occurrences of an element in that new structure.

I'm wondering if there's a different, better way to do this, or if that solution would be considered efficient?

Answer (score 1):

That solution will be efficient, if implemented "properly".  If you're using a package with a vectorized array type, then use the `shift` operation to get the vector of differences.  That's **O(N)** with or without the vectorization.

A second linear pass will find the mode of the array, yielding your final answer.  Keep a simple array to count how many times each value appears:

```
for item in diff_array:
    mode_ct[item] += 1
```

Then find the max of `mode_ct`; return its index.

Comment: How exactly do you mean "A second linear pass will find the mode of the array"? If you're just passing through the array to find the mode, wouldn't that have to be O(N^2)?

Comment: Still a little confused; if the diff_array is containing the differences, then the mode_ct's size is what?

Comment: `mode_ct's` size is the maximum difference.  If you have values that are spread all over the map, such that an array that size is impractical, then use a simple hash map for an array of size `N-1` (the quantity of diffs); this still gives you **O(1)** access to each array element.

Comment: So would you say that solution is preferable over the O(N^2) solution?

Comment: (1) Yes, for a sufficiently large array, an **O(N)** solution is preferable to **O(N^2)**.  (2) I'm not sure what you mean by *the* **O(N^2)** solution, as we don't have one in this thread.